# Нужен ли вопрос в конце предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужен ли вопросительный знак в конце данного предложения и почему: *Уточните, удобно ли вам оплатить общий счет по ссылке(?/.)*

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, как мне кажется, сформулирован некорректно.

Вариант редактирования:

(1) ***Сообщите, удобно ли вам оплатить общий счет по ссылке.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным (косвенная речь), роль союзного средства выполняет вопросительная частица ЛИ. Вопросительный знак в общем случае не ставится.

(2) ***Сообщите, удобно ли вам оплатить общий счет по ссылке?***

Вопросительный знак можно поставить, если вы хотите подчеркнуть вопросительную интонацию.

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

4. Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если вопрос содержится и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, **либо в придаточной:** *Вы знаете, что такое сестры милосердия?* (Остр.);

**Примечание.** Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит **косвенный вопрос,** то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится: *Я прервал речь Савельича вопросом, сколько у меня всего денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться (Н. О.).*

Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит **сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию**, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак: *Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л. Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М. Г.)*

Comment: Благодарю за подробное разъяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то оба варианта допустимы.
Зависит от того, как понимать грамматику фразы. Если "уточните" считать как вводное, то вопросительный знак нужен. Если же рассматривать как сложноподчинное предложение, то причин для знака нет.

В деловом письме я бы скорее предпочел второй вариант: без вопросительного знака.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.